# android :gap between two textview in relative layouts

Tags: android, textview

Android: I want to have gap of 20 dp between two textview i am using relative view and have already used textview 2 should be below textview 1 , but i dont understand how to give more gap in between these 2 textviews

Comment: can you paste your xml code

Comment: share your code

Comment: Did the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use padding or margin. I recommend margin.

```
<TextView 
   android:text="text"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/your_id"
   android:layout_margin="20dp" />
```

EDIT:

Thanks to @Gabe Sechan to amplify the answer. If you want margin only in one side, you can use the specific margin instruction of the side you want. Example:

**Margin only on bottom**

```
<TextView 
  android:text="text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/your_id"
  android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
```

**And the other sides**

`android:layout_marginTop`, `android:layout_marginLeft` and `android:layout_marginRight`.

Comment: You probably want to use something more specific that layout_margin, as you rarely want the same amount of padding on all 4 sides (instead use layout_marginTop, bottom, start, or end in some combo).  But margin is the right answer in general.